# on android 8, will the background child process get suspended when app has a service and a notification in the foreground?

Tags: android

my app has a proxy server in a native executable written by C, it always runs in the background, let's call it httpproxy.exe.
The main activity I use startForegroundService and startForeground with a persist notification to keep the app in the foreground avoid killing by system, then run the httpproxy.exe in the background.

my app works well on android 5 and older verisons, but on android 8.0, when the activity goes background after minutes, httpproxy.exe looks like getting suspended, so I have to bring my app up time after time, that's unacceptable.

I heard there are a so-called Background Execution Limits on android 8，
how can I have my app normally work like before?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) a foreground service should be enough, are you trying this on an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: tested on my actual device

Comment: Besides the doze mode suggestion, which seems a bit unlikely after just a few mins, check if you have some resource management app installed (like samsung smart manager). These kind of apps could very aggressively kill other apps in bg

Comment: My device is HUAWEI honor 9  with EMUI 8.  also set my app allow in background, I highly doubt this could be a bug in EMUI 8.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bug, I'm saying that some vendors implements aggressive policies when it comes to background execution. For instance, some android implementation will kill your bg app when the screen is turned off. I suggest you to try your app with a stock android 8 (like an emulator) and check that it works there

Comment: on a NOKIA 7 android 8.0 , my app now everything normally works like before.

Comment: like before what?

Comment: like on android 5 and older verisons,  with no problems

Comment: And why do you think is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, that your app is excluded from the [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

Checking:

```
PowerManager powerManager =
     (PowerManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);

powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Asking the user to white-list your app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Adding my app to white-list have tested, and I can see isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations return true, nothing changed, but issue looks like is Doze mode related, when I unplug data cable,  httpproxy.exe get suspended in seconds.

Comment: You will probably need to [keep your device awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu).

Comment: a httpproxy doesn't need to keep device awake,  when user using tweet or browser through the httpproxy, device is already awake, it just needs functioning normally in background when user tweeting or wacthing youtube, so don't have to bring app up time after time.

Comment: Please post the code of your foreground service. Without that I can only guess... My next guess would be the [wifi lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html).

Comment: I've tested my app on NOKIA 7 android 8 and works nicely,  maybe this issue is specific to HUAWEI EMUI 8,  anyway, thanks for your idea.